# Using java -jar with loop and insert delay on execution

Tags: windows, loops, cmd, delay

I am using CMD C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe.

I would like to write a batch file (.bat) or write a command in order to run my java -jar example.jar
and when execution is completed I would like to add a loop to start again and again with the same example.jar until ends but before the loop starts I would like to add delay in milliseconds or minutes etc... between those loops.

PLEASE ADVISE!

Thanks
A

Comment: There is a [timeout](https://ss64.com/nt/timeout.html) command in modern Windows.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a VBS or Powershell script to handle the pause/sleep/delay aspect, and simply have your batch file call it.

There are also some freeware utilities out there you could find on Google, perhaps search for `sleep.exe`, etc.

You could code a loop in the batch file but that's a terribly inefficient way to do it.  You could record the time before the loop (using environment variable `%TIME%` or similar approaches), then check the time inside the loop.  But if you want a variable amount of hang time, you'll need to code all the conversions and computations yourself -- not the best use of CPU time.  But it could be done, if you are constrained against using VBS, PowerShell, or third-party utilities.